# How to call a function on gravity forms dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a dropdown in my gravity forms and I would like to be able to dynamically display an image that corresponds with the current selection, and changes when the dropdown selection changes.  The FormID = 1, and form field = 6, and element ID="input_1_6".

How do I call a function on dropdown selection change? I am thinking of using Javascript, but am open to php if it's easier/faster/smarter/etc.

Comment: You'd need to work with JavaScript to detect when the user changes the dropdown selection. Upon change, you'd best ping the server via Ajax to grab the image url you need to dynamically display. Or you can grab all the image urls associated with the dropdown and output them directly to JavaScript to save yourself pinging the server. Which choice is better depends how large your list is and if outputting all the URLs directly to JavaScript is practical.

Comment: Thanks - I am asking how, specifically, to detect when the user changes the dropdown.  It won't be a problem to write a function to display an image.

Comment: JavaScript has an `onchange` event handler. Simply define one for your dropdown and have it call your callback function to update your image. For example: `<select onchange="alert(this.selectedIndex);"><option value="1">a</option><option value="2">b</option></select>`. To get the value use `this.value`. To get the text, use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: Gravity forms dynamically generates the form html, so I don't have access to add an `onchange`.

Comment: jquery can add an event handler to the element for you. See https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: That's the stuff!!  Thanks a lot!